# React Calculator: How to prevent multiple decimals in a number using Math-expression-evaluator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, calculator

As the title says I am using a math-expression library to do my calculations but I am having trouble figuring out the logic for decimals and how to prevent two decimals in one number **inside an array.** I have highlighted the part that is giving me trouble.
Here is my code sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-frost-2s6v6?file=/src/HookClaculator.js:181-2221

```
  const [input, setInput] = useState([0]);
  const [notANum, setNotANum] = useState("");
  const [AC, setAC] = useState("");

  const handleInputOneClick = (e) => {
    let checkInput = input;
    checkInput = [...checkInput, parseInt(e, 10)];
    console.log(checkInput);

    if (checkInput[1] !== 0) {
      setInput([...input, parseInt(e, 10)]);
      if (input.length > 23) {
        console.log("exceeded 23");
        setInput(["MAX DIGIT LIMIT REACHED"]);
        setTimeout(() => {
          setInput([0]);
        }, 500);
      }
    }
  };

  const handleSymbolClick = (e) => {
    if (Number.isInteger(input[input.length - 1])) {
      setInput([...input, e]);
    } else if (input[input.length - 1] === ".") {
      setInput([...input, e]);
    } else if (typeof input[input.length - 1] === "string") {
      input.pop();
      setInput([...input, e]);
    }
  };

  const handleDecimalClick = (e) => {
    if (input[input.length - 1] === ".") {
      setInput([...input]);
    } else if (isNaN(input[input.length - 1])) {
      setInput([...input, e]);
    } **else if (Number.isInteger(input[input.length - 1])) {
      setInput([...input, e]);
    }**
  };

  const handleEqualsClick = (e) => {
    let exp = "";

    if (input[0] === 0 && input.length <= 1) {
      console.log("hell yeah");
      setNotANum(["NaN"]);
    } else if (input.length > 1) {
      console.log("input length is " + input.length);
      input.forEach((el) => {
        return (exp += el);
      });

      let value = mexp.eval(exp);

      setInput([value]);
    }
  };

  const handleClickReset = (e) => {
    setAC(e);
    setInput([0]);
  };

  return (
    <div id="calculator-div">
      <HookDisplay input={input} notANum={notANum} AC={AC} />
      <HookButtons
        inputOneClick={handleInputOneClick}
        symbolClick={handleSymbolClick}
        decimalClick={handleDecimalClick}
        handleEqualsButtonClick={handleEqualsClick}
        handleClickReset={handleClickReset}
      />
    </div>
  );
};


  return (
    <div id="calculator-div">
      <HookDisplay input={input} notANum={notANum} AC={AC} />
      <HookButtons
        inputOneClick={handleInputOneClick}
        symbolClick={handleSymbolClick}
        decimalClick={handleDecimalClick}
        handleEqualsButtonClick={handleEqualsClick}
        handleClickReset={handleClickReset}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think before pushing the decimal to the array you can ensure if it'll create a valid expression.
As currently the calculator supports basic operations, a number can never have more than one decimal and operands can only be one more than than the operators, leveraging the stated fact. This condition will work (inside handleDecimalClick):

```
let lastIndex = -1;
for (let i = input.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (input[i] === ".") {
    lastIndex = i;
  } else if (
    input[i] === "+" ||
    input[i] === "-" ||
    input[i] === "*" ||
    input[i] === "/"
  ) {
    break;
  }
}

if (lastIndex !== -1) return;
```

Also, for extra protection, added a regex to check if the expression is valid before it goes for evaluation (added the below lines in handleEquals):

```
const inp = input.join("");
const regex = /(?:(?:^|[-+_*/])(?:\s*-?\d+(\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?\s*))+$/;
if (!regex.test(inp)) {
  return;
}
```

I forked your [codesandbox and added the fix.](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-mclaren-j0xil?file=/src/HookClaculator.js:1129-1324)